# Error in loading fixtures on symfony with hautelook/alicebundle

Tags: php, symfony, testing, configuration, fixtures

I use hautelook-alice bundle to load fixtures on my test and dev environment. I assume it's installed properly as it worked fine before.
But now I get an error when I run this command:

```
php bin/console hautelook:fixtures:load --no-interaction.
```

I get this error:

```
There are no commands defined in the "hautelook:fixtures" namespace.
```

Here is the hautelook_alice.yaml file:

```
when@dev: &dev
    hautelook_alice:
        fixtures_path: fixtures

when@test: *dev
```

and I have a "fixtures" folder at the root of my project. Finally, the bundle is installed.

Thanks for reading